# Elsticsearch report Missing words in query result

Tags: elasticsearch

One of the features of google is that it reports the missing words in results to the user.

for example if user searches for 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' and one of the result records miss the word "dolor" google will tell the user that this word is missing from this result.

```
Missing: dolor
```

is it possible to implement such behavior in Elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use "explain" and parsing the result to extract missing words

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html

but i'm looking for a more natural way to do this.